# Samba configuration for LAMP server

Tags: networking, windows, apache2, samba, lamp

I am new to ubuntu and samba in general, so please forgive my ignorance.  I am trying to set up my server at home so that I can update the .html files on the server from my windows pc.

Here is the configuration that I have now:

```
[mattmooseHTML]
comment = HTML FILES
path =/var/www/html/
browseable = yes
guest ok = yes
writeable = yes
read only = no
```

I am getting the File Access Denied error:
 You require permission from Unix\root to make changes to this file
 when I try to overwrite or save anything in that folder. 
What do I need to do?

Comment: "I am getting an error." Maybe share that as an [edit] to the question so we don't have to install the "mind reader" package?

Comment: I added that edit, my apologies. Also I just tried editing file in nano on the device and get "Permission denied" error unless I am in sudo. Is there something that I have to do to give permissions to user or to open it up to guest?

Comment: Hmmm. It's unclear to me what your question is. Are you having trouble _editing_ the SMB conf file, or having trouble accessing files on a filesystem shared by SMB? Make sure it is clear in your question what you are trying to do, exactly.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html